# Java guava Splitter failing when there are duplicate keys

Tags: java, guava

How we can handle duplicate keys while using java guava Splitter function. Here is the sample code which is encountering the following issue. Is there a better way to handle this issue.

```
String fieldSplit = " ";
String valueSplit = "=";
String message = "ip=1.2.9.0 error=NA ip=1.2.9.0";
Map<String, String> parserMap = Splitter.on(fieldSplit).omitEmptyStrings().withKeyValueSeparator(valueSplit).split(message);
```

> Exception in thread "kv-plugin-ac801a38-66f1-4ffe-86ca-f9eb6c823842-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=kv-input, partition=0, offset=22, stacktrace=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate key [ip] found.

Im getting the above error. Can somebody suggest a better way to handle this. Since im new to java.

Comment: What are the semantics of the message?

Comment: What do you want with the second occurrence of the key? Discard? Overwrite value? Create a list?

Comment: create a list or discard depends.

Comment: The delimitter message it can change based on inputs.

Comment: Is the order in which the keys/values appear in the message important? (Note that Pavel's answer doesn't give you the result in the same order as the message)

Comment: Order not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do with the duplicate keys.
`Map<String, String>` is a key value storage that can have only unique keys and only one value.

If you want to store all those values you would need something like `Map<String, List<String>` or Guava `Multimap`.

In this case you cannot do this with the Splitter as it cannot handle duplicate keys. You would need to write the logic by yourself.

```java
String fieldSplit = " ";
String valueSplit = "=";
String message = "ip=1.2.9.0 error=NA ip=1.2.9.0";

Map<String, List<String>> parserMap = new HashMap<>();

for (String part : message.split(" ")) {
  String[] subparts = part.split("=", 2);
  if (!parserMap.contains(subparts[0])) {
     parserMap.put(subparts[0], new ArrayList<>());
  }
  parserMap.get(subparts[0]).add(subparts[1]);
}
```

If you want to omit those duplicate entries you can still use the `Map<String, String>` with something like this.

```java
Map<String, String> parserMap = new HashMap<>();

for (String part : message.split(" ")) {
  String[] subparts = part.split("=", 2);
  if (!parserMap.contains(subparts[0])) {
     parserMap.put(subparts[0], subparts[1]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Throwing on a duplicate key is a [documented behavior of `MapSplitter#split`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.MapSplitter.html#split(java.lang.CharSequence)), so depending on what you want, you have to write your own "key-value" spliter consisting of two splitters. Please look at examples below, you can collect results to map with desired behavior (overwrite or discard) or even try out collecting to [`ListMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/30.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html), but it makes result's values being stored in lists, even if there's only one value.

```
public class SO66139006 {

    private static final Splitter PAIRS_SPLITTER = Splitter.on(' '); // .trimResults().omitEmptyStrings() if necessary
    private static final Splitter KEY_VALUE_SPLITTER = Splitter.on('=').limit(2);

    @Test
    public void shouldOverwriteValuesOnDuplicateKey() {
        //given
        String message = "ip=42.42.42.0 error=NA ip=1.2.9.0";
        //when
        Map<String, String> result = parseOverwritingValues(PAIRS_SPLITTER, KEY_VALUE_SPLITTER, message);
        //then
        assertThat(result) // {ip=1.2.9.0, error=NA}
                .containsExactly(entry("ip", "1.2.9.0"), entry("error", "NA"));
    }

    private Map<String, String> parseOverwritingValues(Splitter pairsSplitter, Splitter keyValueSplitter, String message) {
        return Streams.stream(pairsSplitter.split(message))
                .map(keyValueSplitter::splitToList)
                .collect(toImmutableMap(
                        list -> list.get(0),
                        list -> list.get(1),
                        (oldValue, newValue) -> newValue
                ));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDiscardValuesOnDuplicateKey() {
        //given
        String message = "ip=42.42.42.0 error=NA ip=1.2.9.0";
        //when
        Map<String, String> result = parseDiscardingValues(PAIRS_SPLITTER, KEY_VALUE_SPLITTER, message);
        //then
        assertThat(result) // {ip=42.42.42.0, error=NA}
                .containsExactly(entry("ip", "42.42.42.0"), entry("error", "NA"));
    }

    private Map<String, String> parseDiscardingValues(Splitter pairsSplitter, Splitter keyValueSplitter, String message) {
        return Streams.stream(pairsSplitter.split(message))
                .map(keyValueSplitter::splitToList)
                .collect(toImmutableMap(
                        list -> list.get(0),
                        list -> list.get(1),
                        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue
                ));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAppendValuesOnDuplicateKey() {
        //given
        String message = "ip=42.42.42.0 error=NA ip=1.2.9.0";
        //when
        ListMultimap<String, String> result = parseMultipleValues(PAIRS_SPLITTER, KEY_VALUE_SPLITTER, message);
        //then
        assertThat(result.asMap()) // {ip=[42.42.42.0, 1.2.9.0], error=[NA]}
                .containsExactly(entry("ip", ImmutableList.of("42.42.42.0", "1.2.9.0")), entry("error", ImmutableList.of("NA")));
    }

    private ListMultimap<String, String> parseMultipleValues(Splitter pairsSplitter, Splitter keyValueSplitter, String message) {
        return Streams.stream(pairsSplitter.split(message))
                .map(keyValueSplitter::splitToList)
                .collect(toImmutableListMultimap(
                        list -> list.get(0),
                        list -> list.get(1)
                ));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldThrowByDefault() {
        //given
        String fieldSplit = " ";
        String valueSplit = "=";
        String message = "ip=1.2.9.0 error=NA ip=1.2.9.0";
        //when
        final Throwable throwable = catchThrowable(() -> Splitter.on(fieldSplit).omitEmptyStrings().withKeyValueSeparator(valueSplit).split(message));
        //then
        assertThat(throwable)
                .isInstanceOf(IllegalArgumentException.class)
                .hasMessage("Duplicate key [ip] found.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are these Streams.stream doing?

Comment: It's a helper method from Guava wrapping Iterable in Stream: https://guava.dev/releases/30.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#stream(java.lang.Iterable). You can write `return pairsSplitter.splitToList(message).stream()` instead if using iterable, because for small strings it's a microoptimization but YMMV.